# Uploading nexus artifacts using apache ant

Tags: ant, nexus

I am using apache ant to build artifacts. Finally, all artifacts will be zipped in one zip file. Jenkins plugin 'Nexus Artifact Uploader' will upload this zip file to nexus repository(version 3.x). However, there are frequent incidents where Jenkins machine/admin were unavailable.

I am able to download nexus artifacts using ant get task. I want to upload artifacts using apache ant.

Please Note: I am not supposed to use maven or curl/wget commands. I am expected to achieve it using apache ant only.

Comment: The maven resolver ant tasks can do this:  https://maven.apache.org/resolver-ant-tasks/#Deploy

Comment: @rseddon, as mentioned in my questions description, I can not use maven/curl/wget. The machine has only jdk and apache ant configured. There is no internet connection. So, can not download maven dependencies.Also, I am not authorized to use curl/wget commands.